# Which open source CFML frameworks have substantial automated testing for their core features?

Tags: coldfusion, open-source, railo

I'm curious if there are any free open source projects written with ColdFusion (CFML) that have substantial unit testing or other forms of automated testing already done for the core features?

I'd like to consider basing some of my open source project on existing code if the implementation is following more best practices and has automated tests.

For example, a library for handling form / validation.  A library for string manipulations.  Database handling, etc.

Edit: MXUnit is fine for unit testing framework, but I'm asking more about non-testing frameworks that have implemented unit tests to verify their features.

Comment: https://github.com/mxunit/mxunit

Comment: When you say "Open Source CFML frameworks" are you referring to things like FW/1, ColdBox, etc? Or are you referring to automated testing tools that work well with ColdFusion?

Comment: Like James, I'm unclear on what you're asking.  Do you want a testing tool for your own code, a framework that let's you unit test your code easily, or a framework that was written by its curators with its own unit tests?

Comment: So, Bruce, you're asking if like FW/1 / ColdBox / etc have full unit test coverage, and do they actually *ship* with the tests included? Or asking whether they come with their own testing framework? What is it you're trying to get an answer for here?

Comment: I think letting the public have access to the unit tests is the ultimate form of open source to ensure project stays useful beyond original developers desire to work on it.  A project with any aspect of closed development is less useful.      I am looking for substantial platforms or frameworks for CFML that have already implemented substantial open source automated testing.   At a glance, I'm not sure this exists for CFML yet.  The best php equivalent is Symfony2.  It follows modern conventions across a large library and has substantial unit testing (~50% of the source code for tests).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to get involved in an open source project that is pro-unit testing and involves form / validation then have a look at ValidateThis - http://www.validatethis.org/

When I've added to the framework in the past the guys supporting it have asked for tests to be included where at all possible so there should be plenty there to get you started. I'd advise asking on the VT forums for more information and on how you can support the project.

If you're looking for a unit testing framework for your own projects then I'd recommend MXUnit (http://www.mxunit.org/) which is certainty the most popular U.T. tool in the ColdFusion community at the moment.

In terms of application frameworks that have built in testing features I can only comment on one and that's ColdBox (http://www.coldbox.org/) which I know is built upon MXUnit but also includes a pile of other features including their own mocking tool - Mockbox (http://wiki.coldbox.org/wiki/MockBox.cfm)

Comment: It's worth mentioning that ColdBox is currently developing a BDD/XUnit-type testing engine called TestBox.  It will be released in the next month or so.

Comment: I'm curious if others agree with this answer.  I will wait a few days and revisit this.  My app will be open source, and what I'm looking for is to have fewer objections to people wanting to work on my code by following the conventions and frameworks they already like or decide to implement all my own unit testing and ignore the third party projects entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Bruce, The ColdBox MVC Platform has always published its Unit Tests as  part of the GitHub repo:
https://github.com/ColdBox/coldbox-platform/tree/master/testing/cases.

Since you mentioned validation, here are the tests specifically for ColdBox's validation engine:
https://github.com/ColdBox/coldbox-platform/tree/master/testing/cases/validation

You will need to tweak some settings to run them locally, but they are all there.

Since you mentioned wanting to build reusable libraries, please check out ColdBox plugins (for small chunks of reusable code) and ColdBox Modules (For more complex functionality that uses all pieces of the MVC platform).

Comment: I appreciate the extra feedback you've given about coldbox.  I sent a new set of questions to the coldbox google group.  I can see how that project appears to be more substantial and ahead of other all-inclusive open source CFML framework projects.   What I can't see yet is if I'll get frustrated or stuck trying to migrate existing code to work with a third party project like coldbox and the upgrade path down the road.